# Аналог push() для объектов

Tags: массивы, javascript, объекты, функции

Всем привет. Сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой. Мне понадобилось добавлять элементы в ассоциативный массив. На `JavaScript` нет ассоциативных массивов ,поэтому я сделал как объект. Теперь не могу найти аналог функции `push()`. Подскажите, если кто-нибудь знает. Спасибо.

Comment: чем вас такой подход не устраивает?

     var dictionary = {};
     dictionary['FirstKey'] = 'FirstValue';
     dictionary['SecondKey'] = 42;
     dictionary['ThirdKey'] = function(){...};

Comment: Хотелось бы `dictionary.push('value')`. Чтобы ключи сами увеличивались на 1. В моем случае - `obj['key'].push('value')` (не работает).

Comment: Не совсем. Первый ключ - какое-то слово, второй ключ - числа.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

вы хотите, чтобы ключами были обычные инкрементирующиеся числа?

> Не совсем. Первый ключ - какое-то слово, второй ключ - числа.

```
obj['key'] = [];
obj['key'].push('value1');
obj['key'].push('value2');
obj['key'][0];// 'value1'
obj['key'][1];// 'value2'
```

Answer (score 5):

Через цикл не сложно заполнить объект по типу ключ - значение из массива.

```
var dataRow = ['string1', 'string2', 'string1'];
var obj = {};
$(dataRow).each(function(e, i){
    obj[e] = i;
});

// e - индекс ячейки в массиве. 
// i - содержание ячейки, там может быть что угодно.
```

На выходе получим:

```
Object {0: "string1", 1: "string2", 2: "string1"}
```

Или можно так:

```
var dataRow = [{name: 'John', data: "text1"}, {name: 'Mark', data: "text2"}, {name: 'Tom', data: "text3"}];
var obj = {};
$(dataRow).each(function(e, i){
    obj[i.name] = i.data;
});
```

На выходе будет:

```
Object {John: "text1", Mark: "text2", Tom: "text3"}
```